# Uniformly convergent sequence of functions converging to a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a function that I know has pointwise convergence. Is it possible for that function to be uniformly convergent to a piecewise funtion?

Comment: A trivial example is $f_n=f$ everywhere and $f$ is piecewise defined

Comment: Very slightly less trivial, $f_n(x) = f(x) +1/n$ for a piecewise $f$.

Comment: What you **can't** have is a sequence of continuous functions converging uniformly to a discontinuous function.